# update multiple rows with one update button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 data. What I want now is to update them all using a one button but I don't know how to start or how can I get the id of each data. When the data is updated it should alert the updated value.

Any suggestions for this? Thanks

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('bookCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.book = {
        name: 'Session Invites',
        friends: [{
            'id': 1,
                'name': 'raju'
        }, {
            'id': 2,
                'name': 'radha'
        }, {
            'id': 3,
                'name': 'luttappi'
        }]
    };
    $scope.update = function (friend) {

        alert(friend.name);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in book.friends">
      <input type="text" ng-model="friend.name" />
      
    </div>
     <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update(friend)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "update" precisely. Also, if you want one button, it shouldn't be inside the ng-repeat, otherwise, you'll have one button for each friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Doing a `forEach` on `book.friends` and send the `book.friends`(being modify in the html)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('bookCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.book = {
        name: 'Session Invites',
        friends: [{
            'id': 1,
                'name': 'raju'
        }, {
            'id': 2,
                'name': 'radha'
        }, {
            'id': 3,
                'name': 'luttappi'
        }]
    };
    $scope.update = function (friends) {

        $scope.book.friends.forEach(function(v, i){
            v.name = friends[i].name;
        });

        console.log($scope.book.friends);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in book.friends">
      <input type="text" ng-model="friend.name" />
      
    </div>
     <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update(book.friends)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not pure angular way. But gets the job done.

You will need to iterate through the objects and set them all to a given name.

> $scope.update =function(selectedfriend){
>   angular.forEach($scope.friends, function(friend, index) {
>
> friend.name = selectedfriend.name
>
> }); }

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="bookCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="friend in book.friends">
      <input type="text" ng-model="friend.name" />
    </div>
     <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update(friend)" />
  </div>
```

You are passing `friend` in the `update`. But it is undefined I guess. Pass `book.friends` and find updated results

```
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="update" ng-click="update(book.friends)" />

    $scope.update = function(friends) {
    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        var friendId = friends[i].id;
    }
    alert(friends);
};
```